# Very basic question about a rotating rod's kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

I have been trying to understand how to calculate the kinetic energy of a rotating rod that also has translational movement. I have written my question down on paper because I think it is more clear this way.

In case B, I think I have miscalculated the kinetic energy when dividing it as the sum of the rotational and translational energy. I have been days trying to understand this high school level problem. I would be very thankful if someone can point out my error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the kinetic energy in each case is

$$T=\frac 12 m\,\vec v\cdot\vec v+\frac 12 I_{\rm cm}\,\omega^2$$

where $~I_{\rm cm}=\frac 13 m\,L^2~$ and $~\vec v~$ is the velocity at the center of mass

starting with the position vector $~\vec P~$ to the center of mass you obtain

**Case I**

$$\vec P= \frac L2
\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\ \cos \left( \varphi  \right) \end {array}
 \right] 
\quad\Rightarrow \vec v=\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial \varphi}\,\omega$$

$$T={\frac {7}{24}}\,m{L}^{2}{\omega}^{2} $$

**Case II**

$$\vec P=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} \frac L2\sin \left( \varphi  \right)\pm x 
\\ \frac L2\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \end {array}
 \right]
\quad\Rightarrow \vec v=\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial \varphi}\,\omega+\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial x}\,v_x $$

$$T=\frac{m}{24}\,\left( 7\,{L}^{2}{\omega}^{2}\pm 12\,\omega\,L\cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) {\it v_x}+12\,{{\it v_x}}^{2} \right)
$$

where $~v_x=\dot x~$

**Case III**

$$\vec P=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} \frac L2\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\ \frac L2\cos \left( \varphi  \right)\pm y \end {array}
 \right]
\quad\Rightarrow \vec v=\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial \varphi}\,\omega+\frac{\partial \vec R}{\partial y}\,v_y $$

$$T=\frac{m}{24}\,\left( 7\,{L}^{2}{\omega}^{2}\pm 12\,\omega\,L\cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) {\it v_y}+12\,{{\it v_y}}^{2} \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine has provided an answer I believe to be right, so I post it in case anyone was confused by this.

In my original question, I propose 2 methods to solve this problem. The first one, To, is wrong. The second one, Tcm, is the right one. It considers the translational energy of the Center of Mass and the rotational energy around it. **Although the rod rotates around its extreme, the moment of inertia around its Center of Mass must be used** for the rotational component. My colleague provided the answer using integration. I post it as a picture.
[image]
[image]
What seems rather confusing is that the **energy in case B and case C are not the same**. This doesn't violate the conservation of energy principle because, couterintuitively, case C is not what you would get if you let the rod in case B rotate 90° (in 0 gravity). If, in case B where the hinge is originally moving at v0, the rod rotates 90° counterclockwise, the hinge would not be moving at v0 because of conservation of linear momentum.